# How to auto adjust the height of jQuery Colorbox in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm using "Colorbox - a jQuery lightbox" plugin for my website.I'm having the content of varying size which is to be displayed in a colorbox. So for it I want to make the height auto. How can I do this? My current script is as follows:

```
<a href="{$control_url}modules/questions/match_question.php?op=get_question_detail&question_id={$qstn.question_id}#searchPopContent" title="View question" class="inline_view_question_detail">QUE{$question.question_id}</a>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".inline_view_question_detail").colorbox({href:$(this).attr('href'),width:777, height:700});
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

put the height to auto  in you css

```
 height:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to call `$.colorbox.resize()` from the onOpen event. This will automatically fit the colorbox to your content no matter what size it is. In your case, try this code:

```
<a href="{$control_url}modules/questions/match_question.php?op=get_question_detail&question_id={$qstn.question_id}#searchPopContent" title="View question" class="inline_view_question_detail">QUE{$question.question_id}</a>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".inline_view_question_detail").colorbox({
        href: $(this).attr('href'),
        width: 50%,
        height: 50%,
        onOpen: $.colorbox.resize
      });
    });
</script>
```